# Selecting everything in string except last words matching regex expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to grab a brand from a website. Sometimes the name has an extra word that I don't want to capture. For instance, I want to grab `Kitchen Aid`, but the site has `Kitchen Aid Appliances`. Another example is `Maytag Appliance` - note that the first has `Appliances` with an `'s'` and the second has `Appliance` with no `'s'`.

I have a regex expression that I thought would work but it's not. I'm not sure the reason why.

```
^(\w.+)(\sAppliances?)?$
```

The `?` should match zero or one of `'s'` on `Appliance(s)`. The first group should be all the words before the `Appliance(s)`. So it should grab `Kitchen Aid` or `Maytag`.

Also some brand may not have `Appliance` or `Appliances` included. I could have `GE` or `Thermador` listed and just grab it.

I would appreciate any help on this and clarification on what this code is doing if not matching my use case.

Comment: Why did you put it in square brackets?

Comment: `(.*)\sAppliance|Appliances`  Worked for me in Rubular. You can also try using `split` and dropping the last array element if it matches.

Comment: Please add a small example. Include one or more strings, each with a variable assigned to (e.g., `s0 = "I like my Miele Appliances"`) and for each show the string you wish to be returned.

Comment: Also this, a non capturing group: `(.*)\sAppliance(?:s*)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
/^([\w ]+) (?:Appliance)s?/m
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/FX4cuR/1/)

Update (you want *Appliance* to be optional):

```
/^([\w ]+?)(?: Appliance| Appliances)?$/m
```

But that is not really very discriminating.

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/FX4cuR/2/)

You might look at using a hash with a dynamic regex that has alternates of the brands of appliances you are looking for:

```
/^(Kitchen Aid|Maytag|GE|Thermadore)(?: Appliance| Appliances)?$/m
```

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/FX4cuR/4/)

Comment: /^([\w ]+) (?:Appliance)s?/m works but if I'm comparing against a brand that doesn't have 'Appliance next to it I'll want to match it. So it should work with 'Kitchen Aid', 'Kitchen Aid Appliances' and 'Kitchen Aid Appliance'.

Comment: You did not state that. Please give some examples. Do you only want to match the names of brand name appliances? If you make `Appliances` optional, the regex will just match any group of words.